# Why isn't my callback invoked?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
var handler = new Handler();

var iife = (function() {
    return {
        doAlert: doAlert
    };

    function doAlert() {
        alert('testing');
    }
})();

function Bar(){
  this.doFirst = function(){
    handler.add("x", iife.doAlert);
  }
}

function Handler(){
  this.add = function(caption, callback){
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(caption);
    var href = document.createElement("a");
    href.appendChild(linkText);
    href.setAttribute("href", "#");
    href.setAttribute("onclick", callback);

    $(".bc").append(href);
  }
}
```

Given this code, my callback is visible in the Dom as

```
function doAlert() {
    alert('testing');
}
```

This is literally in my `onclick` attribute. Obviously this is not what I want. What do I need to do so it will display my alert? I was expecting to see something like `doAlert()`, why isn't this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute values are strings. Since you are passing a function, its `.toString()` method is implicitly called to set the attribute value for `onclick`.

Never use `onclick` attributes. [Use `addEventListener` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```
href.addEventListener("click", callback);
```